Was the entire planet the Garden of Eden? If not, what what was the purpose of the rest of the planet?
As I understand it, when Adam and Eve committed the Original Sin, God cast them out from the Garden of Eden to live in the planet we have now.
To cast someone out, means there must be 2 places, here and there. This gives me the impression of the Garden being a separate place from current Earth. If that is the case, why make a planet as big as ours is (in relation to its then-current inhabitants), only to focus on a Garden? Why not make a whole perfect planet?
If the entire earth was the Garden, how does one get cast out of it? Is it just a fancy way of saying "So God made the planet kind of sucks in comparison"?
That is my opinion, which I have shown some reasoning for. However, I seek to know if the Bible's account can be shown to support this, or if it does not allow for any such idea.

why can't the garden have been a place on earth?

God intended for man to reproduce and conquer the earth. Obviously it needed to be bigger than just what two people required

Oh that is the first part of my question. If it's a part of Earth, why make a whole planet and then make a specific portion the Garden?

"why make a planet as big as ours is (in relation to its then-current inhabitants), only to focus on a Garden?" — One might even more so ask the same thing about the incredibly huge universe compared with seemingly insignificant Earth.

These are spiritual concepts, the Tree of Life, The Tree of Knowledge of Good and Evil. The man and the woman were engaged in a spiritual process. There is no geography involved.

Please take our tour to understand what we expect to see in a well-researched question, one that is not based on opinions: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

The Bible does not state that the entire Earth has ever been a paradise-like 'garden'. When God ended the sixth 'day' of creation, everything was good, and the culmination of his material creation was 'very good' (Genesis 1:31). But nowhere does the Bible say that everywhere was designated 'the Garden of Eden'  Then the Genesis account goes into greater detail:

"And the Lord God planted a garden eastward in Eden; and there he put
the man whom he had formed." Genesis 2:8 A.V.

The purpose of this placement was for man to continue the horticultural work of God, and to take on zoology (naming the animals God brought to him). He was told to be a good steward of this earthly creation. Also, he and the woman were given God's mandate to procreate, and to "fill the earth" - to populate it with humans. (Genesis 2:19-24 & 1:27-28) Therein is the information given as to what the purpose of God for the entire planet called Earth was. The question asked by the o.p. is logical - "If the entire earth was the Garden, how does one get cast out of it?" Well, there is nothing in the Bible that says the entire earth was that Garden, the text quoted above showing that it could not be. God planted a specific garden, not a new planet.
There is more to the question here about location, however. Now please consider these quotes from a book called Creation. This is from chapter IV, The River in Eden.

"Eden was not the garden. The garden was in Eden. It was called The
Garden of Eden, but it occupied the east only... [and] had already
been planted in advance of Adam's arrival...
But why? Because in the garden Adam would behold the visible
expression of the mind of Jehovah Elohim for the cultivation of the
earth... [who] had taken the initiative, not only in the Creation, but
in that planting which would bring to light the beauty, order, and
consummation latent in the cultivation of all that he had created
and made...
As Jehovah Elohim had planted, so [Adam] was to plant. As Jehovah
Elohim had laid out the garden eastward in Eden, so he was to extend
the garden throughout Eden. As Jehovah Elohim showed the knowledge of
his glory in a prospect, so he was to realize that vision, till the
earth should be filled with the knowledge of the glory of Jehovah, as
the waters cover the sea." Creation, John Metcalfe, pp.94-96 2008,
http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

Now comes the significance of the river that went out of Eden, becoming four heads (Genesis 2:10).

"Ever flowing, ever increasing, ever branching, to the four corners of
the earth, even to the world's ends, carrying the blessing and
increase of the knowledge of the glory of God... through man's
responsive service in answer to the divine planting, the blessing
should be spread abroad, thence to the regions beyond... The whole
earth should be one garden of delight, a scene of perfect harmony
between heaven and earth, earth and heaven, Jehovah Elohim and man,
Adam and his Maker...
'And the Lord God planted a garden eastward in Eden'. Here is an
exact location. Here Jehovah Elohim chose to locate, and wrought to
plant, the garden of Eden. The present location - even if it could be
estimated since the Fall and after the initial destruction of the
Flood, which it cannot, is immaterial. (Ibid. pp.97-98)

But the eastward aspect is significant, as the place from where light breaks forth; as if to say to Adam every dawn, 'More light is coming'.

"Adam in his innocence was taught even from the first opening of his
eyes that neither he nor this Creation constituted the full revelation
of God's purpose: there was the promise of that purpose. The
consummation was neither full or complete...
For the Lord God is a sun and shield: no good thing will he withhold
from them that walk uprightly. And would no knowledge at all have come
to Adam through him by whom the world was made, that 'I am the light
of the world'? If not, how could it have been said that 'The life was
the light of men'? [John 1:1-18] (Ibid. p.100)

As it takes 158 pages for this book to open up the creation account in Genesis, all I can do is give a tiny few snippets of how the spiritual depth in it needs to be carefully opened up. Bits have been selected pertaining to the question, but if anyone is to be fully persuaded, much, much more needs to be explored, for many false teachings have arisen on the basis of either too literal, or too wildly imagined interpretations. I hope this is helpful.

The garden of Eden was not just any garden, it had special status in the sense that it had trees that were unlike any other trees on the rest of the planet. It had a tree called The tree of knowledge of good and evil and another one called The tree of life, it was a garden specifically designed to be applied in teaching Adam and Eve. God taught them who they were, why He created them and the trees from which they were allowed to eat.
This garden was enclosed and was located at some point on the Euphrates river. The garden was like a holy temple where God visited them daily to talk to them and teach them. Thus, the garden was a Holy Place because the presence of God makes any ground holy.
After Adam and Eve sinned then the garden became unholy and tainted with sin and that is why they had to leave. The garden was pretty spacious for two people, and that is all God needed to populate the gigantic world he created.

An interpretation that is compatible with contemporary science, and at least with Roman Catholic orthodox doctrine (small "o", not Eastern Orthodoxy), is that the garden of Eden refers to the original state of human beings on Earth, not to a particular region.
Thus, when Adam and Even were created the whole planet was the garden of Eden, and after they sinned the whole planet stopped being the garden of Eden.
